# Whitelist Domains in Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

Only whitelisted domains should be allowed to consume the API service.

Below is my Code

```
const domainsList =  require('./domains');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (domainsList.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true)
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
      }
    }
  };

exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors( corsOptions ,req, res, () => { 
         console.log("Domain Whitelisted")
    });
});
```

I'm getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined`

What I'm doing wrong here ? Please guide me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the options where you define the `cors` variable.

```js
const cors = require('cors')({origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (domainsList.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true)
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
      }
    }
});
```

And remove it from the `.sendEmail` function line:

```js
cors(req, res, () => { 
  console.log("Domain Whitelisted")
});
```